# Name for partially disjointed/interrupted chords, Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I am trying to denote something where I play a chord, lets say C, but then then I keep playing the note e (for a whole note) key and stop on the other two notes (c and g). Then i play the g note (or c and g) again as a quarter note. Basically I want a whole note at c and then during that whole note i want quarter notes (e and g) played through that measure. I don't think this will effect the answer but the end of that measure's c note is a whole+1 note and the next measure is g quarter notes.

I am trying to engrave this with Lilypond, but just knowing the name of what this is will probably allow me to find it.

Answer (score 10):

This is the act of engraving different *voices* within a single system. In LilyPond, it is created with the `<< { *voice1goeshere*}  >> \\ << { *voice2goeshere* } >>` construction. [Here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices) is the relevant portion of the LilyPond manual.

As a sample:

```
\version "2.19.84"

\score {
  \relative c'
  <<
    {
      r4 <e g>4 q q | % put the higher voice first
      g g g g |
    }
    \\
    {
      c,1~ | % then the lower voice
      c4 r4 r2 |
    }
  >>
}
```

[image]